# to find sup and inf of given set $A :=$ { ${ x \in \mathbb{R} : 8x-3-4x^2 >0 }$ }

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find Sup and inf of the set { $A := { x \in \mathbb{R} : 8x-3-4x^2 >0 }$ }

I have tried finding roots of the quadratic equation $ 8x-3-4x^2=0$ so i got $x= \frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{3}{2} $ 
I also realized $  8x-3-4x^2 >0 $ for $x\in (\frac{1}{2} , \frac{3}{2}) $

So is Sup=$ \frac{3}{2}$ and inf =$ \frac{1}{2} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 8x - 3 - 4x^2 > 0\} &= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 4x^2 - 8x + 3 < 0 \} \\
&= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: (2x-1)(2x-3) < 0\} \\
&= \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}: \frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{3}{2} \right\}
\end{align*}
Hence, the supremum, the least upper bound, is indeed $\frac{3}{2}$ and the infimum is $\frac{1}{2}$ as you said. Note that neither the sup nor inf is in $A$.